# sorting a certain value python

Tags: python, class, sorting

```
class otherclass:
    def __init__(self,instance,town):
        list=[]
        for i in line.split(','):
            list.append(i)
        self.firstname = str(list[0])
        self.height = int(list[1])
    def__str__(self):
       return '%s %d' %(self.firstname,self.height)

class xray(list):
    def __init__(self, file, town):
        self.file=open(file)
        line=self.file.readlines()
        line1= line[10:]
        for g in line:
            self.append(otherclass(g,town))
    def sort1(self):
        #sort function here
```

So basically there are three classes one xray, otherclass, and town. Basiclly otherclass is creating data attributes for every object then xray is suppose to read the file and create an object for each item (each line) and append it to the self list. I then have to create some functions to sort the data. For example I have to sort everyone by height. This is where I am stuck since how do I call it to sort based on height? so basically when I say x=xray(file,town) and then x.sort1() it prints everyone sorted by height

Comment: Why did you repost this?

Comment: Im trying to figure out how to sort my output based on height

Comment: That's not what I asked. You posted this question [20 minutes ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23020134/classes-and-data-attributes), got a few downvotes on it, deleted that post, and created a new one. Why did you do that?

Comment: no reason in particular

Comment: Please don't do that; there are automated systems in place that *will* penalize you for such behaviour, and the community may also react dimly to re-posting.

Comment: Whoops, wrote out a lengthy answer before I read the comments to realize he didn't deserve one. Damn!

Comment: @AdamSmith lol, you could just delete it...

Comment: @AlexThornton Cutting off MY nose to spite HIS face? I don't mind giving detailed answers, I just prefer to give them to people who deserve to receive them.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're going about this wrong. Classes are for objects, not to group code together. Modules are to group code together. This is different than how some other languages (e.g. Java) do things.

Sorting by an attribute, however, isn't hard. Try this:

```
class Dummy(object):
    def __init__(self,name,height):
        self.name = name
        self.height = height

Adam = Dummy("Adam",72)
Steve = Dummy("Steve",71)
user3521527 = Dummy("user3521527",90) # damn you're tall.

dummies = [Adam,Steve,user3521527]
sorted_dummies = sorted(dummies, key = lambda x: x.height)
```

The stdlib `sort` function accepts a `kwarg` named `key` that accepts a function to run the sort on. In this case, it runs through the `list` `dummies`, pulls out each element of the list, assigns it to `x`, then returns `x.height`. It sorts the elements based on the return from the `key` function, so they'll all be sorted according to their height.

Alternatively, you can implement `__cmp__` in your object.

```
class Dummy(object):
    def __init__(self,name,height):
        self.name = name
        self.height = height
    def __cmp__(self,other):
        """self < other if self.height < other.height"""
        if self.height < other.height: return -1
        elif self.height == other.height: return 0
        elif self.height > other.height: return 1
```

This tells Python how to compare objects of that type, so the regular `sort` function works without a key argument.

```
>>> Adam < Steve
True
>>> Adam < user3521527
False
```